# Firebase Cloud Messaging SW integration with Svelte-Kit

Tags: firebase, sveltekit

Has anyone integrated Firebase Cloud Messaging with Svelte-Kit.  My main issue is registering the firebase-messaging-sw.js.  If placed in the static directory I get a 'Syntax Error for using import outside of a module'.  I've tried adding the file to the src directory, and telling vite about it.  My svelte.config.js looks like this.

```
import adapter from '@sveltejs/adapter-node';
import preprocess from 'svelte-preprocess';

/** @type {import('@sveltejs/kit').Config} */
const config = {
    preprocess: preprocess(),

    kit: {
        adapter: adapter({
            out: 'dist'
        }),
        csrf: {
            checkOrigin: false,
        },
        files: {
            serviceWorker: 'src/firebase-messaging-sw.js'
        }
    },
};

export default config;
```

I am testing using `vite build && vite preview` with no luck.  I feel like i'm missing a simple config to keep the file at the root of the project.

Answer (score 2):

The solution I found was to use 'importScripts' a service worker helper I wasn't aware of.

```
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.10.0/firebase-app.js');
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.10.0/firebase-messaging.js');
```